# How to set Pytorch seed for all files?

Tags: python, random, pytorch, seed

I have different files each importing `random` and pytorch. I want one seed to be able to apply everywhere (for all the imported files) for both `random` and `pytorch`. How can we do this? Just setting seed for `random` and `pytorch` in main.py doesn't do anything, resulting in differently trained models, every time.